# When using get_page($id) is there a way to reference another domain?

Tags: php

Using WordPress, I have an index page that inserts content from a couple of pages using their id number. I know this isn't generally advised but it's extremely effective to my needs. But I have just set up an associates sub-domain. I would like to be able to insert the same content but from the original domain. Is it possible to specify the id and the domain it belongs to? If not; any suggestions? I assume I could use iframe? No idea how to use those yet.

```
<?php
$id = 0000;
$p = get_page($id);
if ( get_post_status ( $id ) == 'publish' ) {
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
}
?>
```

Comment: Use the WordPress REST API.

Comment: does the another domain using the same database?

Comment: In a WP multisite environment, you can use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog

Comment: This ended up not being used. Failed to get email about feedback. Sorry